# Locate and segment rectangles

Tags: c, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to develop a system for locating and segmentate rectangles in an image. The rectangles (I want to find) are large an visible, however, they might be touching each other and the might even overlap a little bit.

I have attached a sample image.

[image]

and here I have outlined (approximately) what I hope to achieve. I know there are many more rectangles on the image (especially the suitcase itself) but I think filtering out false positives based on size should be easy enough.

[image]

From trying to find the solution myself I find that edge detection is pretty easy, but I am unsure how I go from there to actually segment the various objects into different classes.

I do not hope for someone here to post a complete solution, but only get some help into which direction I should be going, which standard methods exists out there.

Answer (score 0):

One possible direction is:

1. Fit straight lines to the edges you have detected.
2. Detect pairs of lines that are perpendicular.
3. Match the pairs to create candidate rectangles.
4. Try to fine tune the lines of each candidate rectangle in order to improve the fit to the image data.
5. Assign a confidence score to each candidate rectangle.
6. Filter the candidates by a score threshold that you have chosen according to your desired precision/recall tradeoff.